# Running PowerShell in Metasploit's Meterpreter?

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm running this command in Meterpreter:

```
execute -H -c -i -f powershell.exe
```

This is the output:

```
Process 2716 created.
Channel 3 created.
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

I waited for about 5 min (in the event it was loading modules or something), but I didn't get a prompt.

Comment: Instead of using meterpreter, have you tried doing it with cmd?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that Meterpreter `execute` generally works by dumping the output of a command to the console. Although -i should allow interactivity, it would probably make more sense to use `shell` instead.

From the shell that spawns (cmd.exe), you should be able to run PowerShell if necessary. Otherwise, you should have a standard cmd.exe shell already.

If running `shell` doesn't work, you might have some other issues with your Meterpreter session.

Hope that helps!